# Xbox One can't turn on and off the TV

Tags: xbox-one, kinect

I've got Kinect for Xbox One. Using "Xbox on" voice command I can't turn on the TV. The same turning off. I can control volume via voice command. The TV is Toshiba (I'm not sure about the model) and Xbox detect it automatically, setting the remote control code to T1524. Is the power switching supported by my TV?

Comment: Can you please verify you have set Kinect to turn on/off your TV when it starts or shuts down? There isn't a separate command. Also, are you on the Preview?